# Soft link local file to a remote file

Tags: tramp

I use emacs on different boxes and I want to share some files between them.
The canonical examples would be [`gnus-startup-file`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/gnus/Startup-Files.html) and [`remember-data-file`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/remember/Text-File.html).

I can set the files to remote locations (like, e.g., `/sds@myserver:~/.newsrc`) and `tramp` would take care of that.
However, `myserver` is not always available and I don't want my `gnus` to freeze when `myserver` goes down.

The behavior I want is *local* files which are synced to a *remote location* every now and then.

For now I do it from [`gnus-before-startup-hook`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/gnus/Startup-Variables.html)/[`gnus-after-exiting-gnus-hook`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/gnus/Exiting-Gnus.html) and [`midnight-hook`](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/MidnightMode), but I was wondering what would others suggest.

PS. Note that these files aren't on the same exalted level as, say, `.emacs` (which is kept under `hg`), so I do not want to preserve their history.

Answer (score 1):

I keep those files in a git repository.  Then I run a script every once in a while which does `git commit; git pull; git push`.  I really wish someone would write a file-system which does that for me.

Comment: [loggedfs](http://loggedfs.sourceforge.net/)? [gitfs](https://github.com/PressLabs/gitfs)? (They both record every write.)

Comment: I don't think these files deserve version control. Those that do are, indeed, kept under `hg`.

Comment: `gitfs` is on the right track I think, but it needs more work.  The way I see it, it should be as commonplace/standard/robust as NFS.  It could be seen as a competitior to owncloud.  As for whether they deserver versioning, I agree they don't except to detect and handle merges/conflicts.

Answer (score 0):

Just put those files in your .emacs.d and symlink to them from your home directory.

That way they'll always be up to date as long as you keep your .emacs.d syncronized.

Comment: I don't understand. How is `.emacs.d` synchronized?

Comment: Rereading your question, I see you said your `.emacs` was in hg, not your `.emacs.d`.  My bad, I use `.emacs.d/init.el` instead of `.emacs` and forget about it sometimes.